# Number of 3-colorings of an n-length cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $C(n)$ be a cycle of length $n$, with $n\ge5$ and let $A(n)$ be the number of ways to color said cycle with the three colours ${1,2,3}$. Give a combinatorial proof that $A(n) = A(n-1) + 2A(n-2)$.

I'm at a bit of a loss on where to start with this. Could anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Number the vertices of the cycle $1$ through $n$ in cyclic order. If vertices $1$ and $n-1$ have different colors, you can remove vertex $n$ to get a properly colored $(n-1)$-cycle. Conversely, given a properly colored $(n-1)$-cycle, you can insert a vertex $n$ between vertices $1$ and $n-1$, and there is only one possible way to color it. That accounts for $A(n-1)$ properly colored $n$-cycles, those in which vertices $1$ and $n-1$ have different colors.

To finish the job, you need to show that there are $2A(n-2)$ properly colored $n$-cycles in which vertices $1$ and $n-1$ are the same color. Consider removing vertices $n$ *and* $n-1$.